# How would I add 301 redirect to htaccess without fouling up my rewrite conditions?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to update my htaccess file because of a change in SEO.  The update is from this style `domain.org` to `www.domain.org`.  So there needs to be a 301 update to the file.

How would I add 301 redirects?  Also, do I need to change the `index.html` sections to `www.index.html` along with the 301 addition?

This is what my htaccess looks like now.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.html?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.html?x=$1&y=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.html?x=$1 [L]
```

I've fouled up htaccess in the past, so I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.html?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.html?x=$1&y=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Oh, so it's only a 2 line addition and it doesn't really affect any of the other lines?